# Is it possible to get the original type of a list when all you have is a "WhereEnumerableIterator" of that list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

It may be simple but nevertheless it has caused us a bit of headache over the past few hours.

Long story short: We need to fix a memory leak and the way to do it is to return the original list without creating a new instance of MyBindingList if ToBindingList is invoked on a list that is already of the type MyBindingList

MyBindingList inherits System.ComponentModel.BindingList

How would you write the extension method ToBindingList() allowing this test passes?

```
[TestMethod]
public void FooBar()
{
    var SUT = new MyBindingList<FooBar>
    {
        new FooBar{Name = "AAA"},
        new FooBar{Name = "BBB"},
    };

    var filteredList = SUT.Where(x => x.Name == "AAA").ToBindingList();

    Assert.AreEqual(1, filteredList.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, ReferenceEquals(filteredList, SUT));            
}

private class FooBar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

MyBindingList constructor goes like this

```
public class MyBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>, IEntityChanged
{
   public MyBindingList(IList<T> list) : base(list) { }

//...
}
```

The problem we encounter is that the extension method operates on an iterator (the Where-clause) so we have no way of comparing the type informatoin of the two lists. We wrote the following extension method and then got wiser - and stuck:

```
public static MyBindingList<T> ToBindingList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> container)
{            
    var returnVal = container as MyBindingList<T>;
    if (returnVal != null)
        return returnVal;                

    return new MyBindingList<T>(container.ToList());
}
```

Can anybody help us here to a viable solution or explain why the compiler will never allow us to do something like this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Won't fix your problem, but why don't you `return returnVal;` instead of doing `container as MyBindingList<T>` **a second time**?

Comment: Of course - thanks. Example has been updated

Comment: You're welcome! Could you by chance add the code for `MyBindingList`?

Comment: There's not much to it inside but it's quite elaborate so I just added the constructor and class initialization. Hope it's OK

Comment: If the `container` isn't a `MyBindingList` don't you need to wrap the `Where` `IEnumerable` anyway - you can't return it from `ToBindingList`... What do you want to happen when the `container` is a `Where` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BindingList<T>` (and more recently, `ObservableCollection<T>`) are just not for this purpose. They meant to wrap a 'final' result of a collection provided by your ViewModel or whatever underlying layer. If you need to filter the list you have basically two options:*

- Return a new instance of the of the `BindingList<T>` (wrapping simple collections instead of another binding list) and rebind your view.
- Handle the 'filtering' by removing the items from the binding list and just allow the view to update accordingly as it processes the notifications of the list change (after all that's why one uses an observable collection such as `BindingList<T>`).

**Remark:* If your View uses WinForms technology, you can use the `BindingSource` type in the form (its `DataSource` can be your binding list), which also implements `IBindingList`. It has a `Filter` property, which is a string and can accept fancy expressions but actually I would not use this property in practice.

Comment: I will mark this as the accepted answer as I TL;DR think you're absolutely right after reading more in-depth about bindinglists.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,979cb1fc22e29394,references), you can do this using Reflection:

```
var data = new List<int>();
var iterator = data.Where(x => 1 == 1);
var type = iterator.GetType();
var sourceField = type.GetField("source", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);    
Console.WriteLine(sourceField.FieldType);
```

Which prints:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
```

You can test this on [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IbqbUE).

So you could do something like this to get the value:

```
public static List<T> GetOriginalList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> whereSource)
{
    var type = whereSource.GetType();
    var sourceField = type.GetField("source", 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField);

    return sourceField as List<T>;
}

public static MyBindingList<T> ToBindingList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> container)
{            
    var returnVal = container as MyBindingList<T>;
    if (returnVal != null)
        return returnVal;                

    return new MyBindingList<T>(container.GetOriginalList<T>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible, but hacky.  Use reflection to check if the type is a nested type whose parent is System.Linq.Enumerable.  If so, use reflection to get the value of the private 'source' instance field.  That is the original source of the Where.  This should work for all Enumerable methods, but I recommend you do this in a loop until you've reached the root source to support more complex querying.  I also recommend caching reflection results in a static place.  Fair warning though - there's no guarantee that 'source' will continue to be the name of the private field in upcoming releases.  To rely on it means you need to re-test this for each and every .NET framework release you intend to run it on.  It might just stop working one day.